# Java - Reversing words in a string

Tags: java, design-patterns, reverse, matcher

This is our code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class reverse {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File fil = new File("textFile.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(fil);

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String in = scan.nextLine();
        in = new StringBuffer(in).reverse().toString();
        Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("\\W+");
        Matcher matcher = replace.matcher(in);
        System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("\t"));
        }



    }

}
```

In our textFile.txt we have letters, numbers and words in different lines. We want print them out in reverse order. So if one line is: Yes, 4 Chocolate milk. We want to print out: milk Chocolate 4 Yes.

Our code prints out words in reverse, so yes becomes sey. We don't want it to be like this, but don't know how to change it. We've been thinking about creating a stack, but we don't how it'll work together with out Pattern and Matcher stuff.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: I would parse all words with Split(" "); and put them in hashmap and reverse. I think, it would be the fastest way to reverse text.

Comment: why in your example output is "Chocolate milk 4 Yes" and not "milk Chocolate 4 Yes"? is it deliberate? If yes, how should the algorithm recognize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't reverse the line you read but split the line into a collection and reverse that.
What you do is reversing the characters, so you get this:

```
Yes, 4 Chocolate milk -> klim etalocohC 4 , seY
```

If you split the line into `["Yes","4","Chocolate milk"]` you can reverse that array/list.

The problem is: I guess you want to keep `Chocolate milk` in that order, so you'd need to define what words belong together. If your input is always `<words>, <number> <words>` you could split on `,` first, to separate the first `<words>` and then on the first whitespace of the remainder in order to split the number and the second `<words>`.

*Update*: try this:

```
String input = "Yes sir, 4 Chocolate milk";

//Pattern is: 
//- one or more words separated by whitespace as group 1: ((?:\\w+\\s*)+)
//- a comma 
//- optional whitespace: \\s*
//- an integer number as group 2: (\\d+)
//- optional whitespace \\s*
//- an arbitrary rest (which might contain anything) as group 3: (.*)
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "((?:\\w+\\s*)+),\\s*(\\d+)\\s*(.*)" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( input );

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while(m.find()) {
  list.add( m.group( 1 ) );
  list.add( m.group( 2 ) );
  list.add( m.group( 3 ) );
}

Collections.reverse( list );
for( String s : list) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

The output should be

```
Chocolate milk
4
Yes sir
```

Note that this depends on the layout of your input and is just meant to provide a start. You'd also need to integrate that with your other pattern matching logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Scanner` or simply `String.split()` to create an `Array` or `Collection` of all tokens within your line. Then just use a `for`-loop to iterate over it backwards to recreate the line. You also could use `Collections.reverse()` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by words, save result into an array of strings and then display the string from last to first element.
Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String hello = "bananas 45 guns me likes 3";
    String[] reverse_me = hello.split(" ");

    // the -1 is because the index starts in zero :-0)
    for(int i = reverse_me.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--){
        System.out.println(reverse_me[i]);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
3
likes
me
guns
45
bananas
```